# Phone stuck on boot screen after root and recovery - HTC One M8

Tags: twrp, htc-one, lineageos, htc-one-m8

Need help with rooting and installing LineageOS. Have done this before on Nexus 5, but today something went wrong with HTC M8 and now it's stuck on boot screen 
I can get into bootloader using Power and volume keys, but any other options as Recovery, Factory reset brings me to just boot screen

1. Did a root and installed superSU successfully
2. Flashed [recovery](https://twrp.me/htc/htconem8gsm.html) and install
3. Something went wrong while installing [LineageOS](https://download.lineageos.org/m8) and did a reboot and since then no progress

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are on the latest compatible baseband of your phone? Sometimes the newer builds of TWRP won't boot on old firmwares. Try updating that first.

And since you have access to your bootloader, you can install recovery and start over with a different ROM (make sure to verify your checksums manually).

Comment: The phone is stuck on HTC boot screen. No matter which options I select, I never get into it. Its always the boot screen.

Comment: @Aniruddha But you mentioned in your question that you can go into bootloader. Is your bootloader accessible or not?

Comment: Yes. I can seee options for HBOOT or FASTBOOT too, but none of it is working as whatever I select it displays HTC white screen with green logo afterwards.

Comment: @Aniruddha Just double check if you are doing the right steps for your device. From what I know, you need S-off and need to untick fastbooot somewhere in settings. Have you tried simply running fastboot commands from the bootloader screen or the HTC one? I think you'll get better help at XDA and not here. (My hunch is that you are simply pressing the wrong buttons, but I could be wrong)